# Reflexive "treffen" when planning to meet someone?

Tags: meaning, verb, pronoun

If I'm **planning** to meet someone (as opposed to simply meeting them), should I use a reflexive pronoun?

> (a) Ich werde ihn treffen.
>
> (b) Ich werde mich mit ihm treffen.

Comment: I changed your sentence (a) to fit in with this question. The original version, _Ich werde mit ihm treffen_, means something different: _With him, I'll score._

Comment: The question seems redundant--to meet someone as opposed to simply meeting them? Do you mean meet them as in being first introduced vs meeting up with them regardless of being the first time or not?

Comment: @Kevin I guess "opposed to" refers to "planning". So, he's asking for what to say when you intentionally meet someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ich werde ihn treffen

The connotation here is that you know you'll meet somebody when you go somewhere. For example as in *Wenn ich in die Kneipe gehe, werde ich Klaus treffen* (as he's always there on Wednesdays).

> Ich werde mich mit ihm treffen

The connotation is that you have an appointment. As in *Ich habe ausgemacht, mich heute mit Klaus in der Kneipe zu treffen*.

Comment: Or slightly different: `jemandem treffen` refers only to the action of the subject, how the object sees that is totally unknown: "Ich werde Thomas am Bahnhof treffen. Das haben wir gerade besprochen.", "Ich werde Justin Bieber treffen, denn ich habe das Meet-n-Greet gewonnen. [Er weiß natürlich noch nicht, wen er da trifft.]" In contrast, `sich mit jemandem treffen` or `sich treffen` refer to action by both parties.

Answer (score -1):

As you are using Future, both your example sentences are about planning to meet someone.

You do not need to use the reflexive Form, but you can.

Comment: Whoever downvoted please give an explanation and/or suggestion comment so the answer can be improved. :-)

Comment: @Kevin i think these downvotes are historically induced... check revision history ;) also there was a nice reason behind it

Comment: My concern is that if revisions were made, then perhaps the vote should be changed. But thx! :-)